# Three JS: How to add images on each vertices of icosahedron

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three js, i was trying to create a rotating icosahedron with small icon kind of images on each vertex using three js, i could create the icosahedron and make it rotate but I'm not able to attach images on each vertex of it. Can anyone help me do this? 
Please check the js fiddle link of what i could acheive so far:

```
<div id="container"></div>

var $container = $('#container');
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, 1, 0.1, 10000);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var Ico;

scene.add(camera);
renderer.setSize(576, 576);

// Making the canvas responsive
function onWindowResize() {

  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth <= 479) {
    renderer.setSize(300, 300);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 767) {
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 991) {
    renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 1200) {
    renderer.setSize(450, 450);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 1366) {
    renderer.setSize(550, 550);
  }
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
onWindowResize();
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);


$container.append(renderer.domElement);

// Camera
camera.position.z = 200;

// Material
var greyMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  emissive: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  specular: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  shininess: "100000000",
  shading: THREE.FlatShading,
  transparent: 1,
  opacity: 1
});

var L2 = new THREE.PointLight();
L2.position.z = 1900;
L2.position.y = 1850;
L2.position.x = 1000;
scene.add(L2);
camera.add(L2);

var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(125, 1), greyMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(Ico);
var trackballControl = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
trackballControl.rotateSpeed = 1.0; 
trackballControl.noZoom = true;

function update() {
  Ico.rotation.x += 2 / 500;
  Ico.rotation.y += 2 / 500;
}

// Render
function render() {
  trackballControl.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  update();
}
render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arunvenugopal11/uoxtmtnr/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As an option, you can use [`THREE.Sprite()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Sprite). One sprite a vertex, with a texture of image you want.

Comment: Hey @prisoner849 Could you please create a fiddle with that sprite implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `THREE.Sprite()`, like this:

```
var txtLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

txtLoader.setCrossOrigin(""); // you don't need it, if you get images from your web site

var textures = [ // you can have a full set of 42 images, I used just 2
  "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg",
  "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/colors.png"
];
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(); // we'll re-use it in the loop

Ico.geometry.vertices.forEach(function(vertex, index){

  var texture = txtLoader.load(textures[index % 2]); // when you have a full set of images, you don't need that operation with modulus '%'

  var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
  var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);

  sprite.scale.setScalar(10); // the size is up to you

  direction.copy(vertex).normalize(); // direction is just a normalized vertex

  sprite.position.copy(vertex).addScaledVector(direction, 10); // add scaled direction to the position of a sprite

  Ico.add(sprite);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/b2tncLh8/) example. r85

Comment: Thanks alot man, everything works perfect, but the images look blurred.  I'm using images of size 128 x 128 pixels still it looks blurred, I even tried SVG images but no luck. Is there any simple hack to make the images look better?

Comment: @Arun 1) If an answer solves your question, then mark it as accepted (as people, at least, spent time on it to make you happy), 2) the question about blurring is out of this topic as your original question was about adding images on each vertex. Thus you can start a new question or try to search for the answer on SO as it was asked many times in the `three.js` tag.

Comment: Hi @prisoner849, Since I'm new to stack overflow and don't know the rules of this platform I couldn't behave like how you expected, apologies for that. And yeah your solution helped me solve my issue, so I will definitely mark it as accepted. I really appreciate you for the kindness you have to help the frontend development community. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: You're welcome ) My comment didn't suppose to be mean.